# how to delete kafka topics created programmatically

Tags: apache-kafka

I am creating the Kafka topic programmatically . when application end . i have to delete the created Kafka topics . I am using adminClient.deleteTopics(TOPIC_LIST) but still topics doe not get deleted instead making marked as "marked for deletion" . Any one know how can i delete topic permanently using java.

Comment: "when application end . i have to delete the created Kafka topics" - can you edit your question to explain *why*? This doesn't sound like a particularly common pattern of usage so it'd be good to understand some more context.

Comment: In my case, I need to delete the topic so that when the next test runs, it has a clean system

Answer (score 0):

The method you're using is correct.

There's no method available to wait for the data on disk to permanently be removed unless you decide to use something like JSSH and manually delete remote file paths from the brokers